# How to add menu items for a single-page web part?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

Is it possible to have menu items added for a single-page web part in the menu bar? I want to add a menu to the area usually used for menu commands (please see the screenshot):

[image]

I am talking about this sort of single-page app web part: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/single-part-app-pages

My question is, it possible to put some items in the designed area, and if yes, how?

I have tried to do it with command set extension (and ECB). The commands are coming for a normal list, but for a single page web part, they are not.

Talking about options, could it be an acceptable to "attach" a component like fabric `CommandBar` to this area (i.e. find it in HTML and attach), or maybe there is a standard way to do that (like, designated placeholders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer here:
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6014

It is not possible right now.